# Unable to move wordpress jquery library into the footer

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load, footer

I have tried every way I know about, and have read about, to move the jquery library to the footer including the following and every possible variation of the following:

```
function add_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.3', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

and

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js','','',true);
```

I'm not sure what version(s) of Wordpress these worked in but they don't work in the latest versions (3.5 - 3.7).  Of course jquery can be deregistered or completely deleted from the script-loader.php file and then hard coded into the footer but the script will not work.  WordPress somehow prevents it from actually loading even though the code to do so is sitting there in the html.  Before anyone says this, while I am attempting to load jquery in the footer, all other javascript will be loaded afterwards so it a question of jquery dependent scripts loading prior to the library.  Also, many of people will say that its not good to load core scripts in the footer which, from a best practices standpoint, may be true but this is irrelevant because Google wants it in the footer and that is all that really matters.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have a wp_footer() hook in your template?

Comment: yes, there is wp_footer() hook

Answer (score 11):

This works (tested on WordPress 3.8 with Twenty Fourteen theme):

```
function md_footer_enqueue_scripts() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'md_footer_enqueue_scripts');`
```

Scripts will be put right before the closing of the `<body>` tag and CSS files will be kept in the `<head>` of the document – considering that they were enqueued with `wp_enqueue_style`.

[wp_enqueue_style (Codex Reference)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: Works for Wordpress 4.4 as well. Tested. Great one.

Comment: Works on my site also. However, I'm confused and would like to know why it works! Specifically, why we don't need to call ```add_action()``` three times like: ```add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);``` to add the scripts back into the WP footer.

Comment: You are simply removing the default WordPress actions that allow any scripts in the document's head. As a result, they will naturally be forced to be enqueued in the footer. There's no need to include more add_action statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if( !is_admin()){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"), false, '1.8.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Already tried it (which is what I meant by all variations of the aforementioned) and it does not work.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is how I managed to include mine, but I use cloudflare instead of google you can easily change that.

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_enqueue');
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" , false, null, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Also if that don't work have you tried with

`add_action('wp_footer' , 'add_scripts');`instead of `add_action('wp_enque_scripts')` in your case?

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but neither moved the library into the footer.  I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the `functions.php` file.
It works for me in WordPress 4.1.2

```
// load jquery in the footer
function ds_enqueue_jquery_in_footer( &$scripts ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $scripts->registered['jquery']->args = 1;
        $scripts->registered['jquery-core']->args = 1;
        $scripts->registered['jquery-migrate']->args = 1;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'ds_enqueue_jquery_in_footer', 11 );
function enqueue_jquery_in_footer() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'enqueue_jquery_in_footer' );
```

Answer (score -5):

In the file wp-includes/script-loader.php, on the ofending render-blocking js scripts, add one last argument with value 1. In my case:

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.10.2', 1 );
$scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.2.1', 1 );
```

This is documented on the same file as:

```
/**
 * Register all WordPress scripts.
 *
 * Localizes some of them.
 * args order: $scripts->add( 'handle', 'url', 'dependencies', 'query-string', 1 );
 * when last arg === 1 queues the script for the footer
```

Comment: It's bad practice to edit core; this will break when wp-includes/script-loader.php is updated.